# Does this drumming technique have a name?

Tags: drums

I just discovered the track "I Got The..." by Labi Siffre and am blown away by it. One quite appealing technical detail is around the 3.25 mark the drummer starts repeating a kind of two bar sequence where each of the two bar sequences starts with a small maybe syncopated flurry and the start of the next bar gets maybe an extra off beat snare hit or something. Is there a technical term for this pattern ? It sounds great anyway.

Link to track on youtube:

Comment: the little flurry is a drag.

Comment: Sounds more like a simple single-handed roll or a buzz (dead) stroke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As b3ko already said in the comments, the "syncopated flurry" is a drag. It consists of hitting twice quietly with the left hand right before a note in the right hand (for right-handed people), as [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTH7BTJAngc) explains. In this case, the left hand notes are snare, and the right hand note is hi-hat + kick drum, the first beat of the bar.

As for this part:

> the start of the next bar gets maybe an extra off beat snare hit or something

there is not such thing IMO, the next bar is very "well behaved", so I think the pattern we are seeing here is just the drag.

Comment: there is that little open hit hat, syncopated snare action before the end of the second bar, maybe that is what the OP means??

Comment: Extra snare at 3.54 for example, extra open high hat at 4.06, several other occassions where i think there are additional less obvious differences.

Comment: @user467257 Aah, I see. It's between beat 4 and beat 1, in the second bar after the drag. Anyway, I don't think it's part of a pattern, nor has a name.....